# Maximizing function with total derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find x (from the differential equation so derived by the FOC condition) by maximizing the following problem with respect to a -

$((x(a))^m)a_1^n + ((1-x(a))^m)a_2^n$

where, $a= (a_1,a_2)$

Can I differentiate above function with respect to both $a_1$ and $a_2$ at the same time? In other words, can we maximize the function using total derivative? Is this mathematically correct?

Note that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are unrelated to each other and there is no condition where I can make the substitution.

Comment: You maximise multi variable problems often by finding the *gradient*; a point where the gradient is zero is a potential maximum, minimum or critical point

Comment: Yes, you can find the differential of your expression and set it equal to zero. This is equivalent to setting its _partial derivatives_ equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you a lot. @Allawonder

Comment: Thanks @FShrike